# Setting up a virtual, bridged, NIC in Windows

Tags: windows, network-adapter, vmware-workstation

When you install VMware Workstation on Windows, it creates several virtual NICs, one of which is directly bridged to a NIC that's connected to the network (somehow, it appears to always be bridged to the NIC that's currently accessing the default gateway).

How do I create such a NIC without install VMware Workstation? I looked into MS Loopback Adaptor but it doesn't appear to be what I need (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Have a Softphone (VoIP) app that needs to use a separate IP from the rest of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this, used by software such as colinux/andlinux -and very likely vmware and other virtualization software is to use [tap/tun drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) to create a virtual interface and use that - very commonly the drivers that are part of openvpn are used on windows.

You'd naturally need to tweak it to your needs, but here's an example of a C# program that uses the [tap/tun interface from openvpn](http://www.varsanofiev.com/inside/using_tuntap_under_windows.htm) to simulate a remote network

Comment: Quite complex, is there one that doesn't involve coding?